# How can I keep all the clips' metadata when exporting a sequence in Adobe Premiere Pro?

Tags: export, metadata, premiere-pro

I have a sequence composed of two subsequent clips in an Adobe Premiere Pro 2022 project. Each clip is a video taken with a GoPro and contains GPS information. However, when exporting the sequence using the export default settings, the GPS metadata is lost (I use this tool to view [GPS data](https://goprotelemetryextractor.com/free/#)). How can I keep all the clips' metadata when exporting a sequence in Adobe Premiere Pro?

---

Adobe Premiere Pro 2022 export options (I'm keeping all the metadata that I was allowed to keep but maybe I messed up something):

[image]

[image]

Comment: I am still interested in this question.

Comment: Any idea is welcome.